# Error generating final archive: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Unknown Android Packaging

Tags: android, packaging

I am getting an error in my Problems tab for any Android Project I create in Eclipse. The error is **"Android Packaging Problem**" with an Unknown location.

```
error generating final archive: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13    test        Unknown Android Packaging Problem
```

I cannot determine what this problem is and cleaning the project is not solving the problem.  The same error appears when relaunching the application. I am using eclipse 3.7.2 32bit with ADT version 20.0.3 and project is using sdk version 4.0.3 15. Can someone give me an idea on what area I can look into?

Comment: Could you please show some of your code?

Comment: Please check your "Caused by": in error stack. This line will give you a reason for the error and the line below will show you where the error is happening and will include a line reference so you can easily find the problem.

Comment: Please post your code and your complete LogCat output here and may be then we can help you.

Comment: i have not added any code of my own. i have just created a test android application project and trying to run the application. but it is not launching because of this and thereby not output in logcat.

Comment: m stuck with this for weeks..

Comment: the error location is unknown and type android packaging problem